# Physical meaning of a mathematical identity

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I have found this mathematical identity which is related to the Caderon identities and I want to understand its physical meaning. Let $S$ be a closed surface with unit normal vector $\mathbf n$ and let $$\mathcal T(\mathbf J) = i \omega \mu \mathbf n \times \int_{S} \frac{e^{-ik|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}}{4 \pi |\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} \mathbf J(\mathbf r')d\mathbf r'$$

Then the following holds: $\mathcal T^2(\mathbf J) = -\frac{\mathbf J}{4} + \mathcal K^2(\mathbf J)$, where

$$\mathcal K(\mathbf J) = \mathbf n \times \nabla \times \int_{S} \frac{e^{-ik|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}}{4 \pi |\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} \mathbf J(\mathbf r') d\mathbf r'.$$

I understand that $\mathcal T$ maps $\mathbf J$ to the electric current field $\mathbf E$. This is because the integral term is the vector potential $\mathbf A$ and by including the factor $i\omega$ this gives the electric field by Faraday's law.

Now, I have trouble understanding the physical meaning of $\mathcal T^2$: since $\mathcal T(\mathbf J)$ is an electric field, what is the meaning of considering $\mathcal T(\mathbf E)$? This should provide again a current since in the above identity it is equal to $-\frac{\mathbf J}{4}$.

But while it is clear that $\mathcal T$ maps $\mathbf J$ to $\mathbf A$ (or the electric field $\mathbf E$, equivalently) as it follows by considering the Green function for the Helmholtz equation, it is not clear what does $\mathcal T$ do when applied to the electric field $\mathbf E$.